# How to create a null reference / unset a reference?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

Consider I have a dataset of references

```
f = h5py.File("test.h5","a")
d = f.create_dataset("refs",(10,),h5py.ref_dtype)
d[0]
#<HDF5 object reference (null)>
```

I can create non null references via the `.ref` attribute of a dataset or group:

```
d[0] = f.create_dataset("data",data=np.arange(5)).ref
d[0]
# <HDF5 object reference>
```

Now assume I want to set the reference back to null, for example to indicate that the referred to thing has been deleted.

How can I do that or, more generally, is there a direct (non `.ref`) way of creating a reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Simply assign `None`.

```
d[0]= None
d[0]
# <HDF5 object reference (null)>
```

Kind of obvious, really...

Sorry for the noise.